# How to avoid multiple computations within `map` callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, closures

I wrote following "one-liner" for normalizing a vector (represented by an usual array here), that means dividing every entry by the euclidean norm of the vector.

```
normalize = v => v.map(x => x/Math.sqrt(v.map(x => x * x).reduce((a, b) => a + b)))
```

Unfortunately it is not very efficient, as the norm is computed over and over again for every entry. Can we modify this "one-liner" in a way that avoids this repeated evaluation?

EDIT: One method I found - which isn't particularly elegant and not very readable - requires adding another input argument to the outermost lambda and using it as an input for the norm:

```
 normalize = w => (norm => w.map(x => x / norm))(Math.sqrt(w.map(x => x * x).reduce((a, b) => a + b)))
```

Comment: Just… *don't* write it in one line and split it up a bit…? Even the initial version is hardly readable. Presumably this isn't code golfing, writing one liners is not a goal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply *don't* try to be too clever…

```
const normalize = v => {
    const norm = Math.sqrt(v.map(x => x * x).reduce((a, b) => a + b)));
    return v.map(x => x / norm);
};
```